# How can i create progress bar based on buttons on my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have more than 23 buttons on my page and they can be decreased or increased.
how can i count all buttons and create progress bar according to status change of button. There are only two status one will increase percentage and another will decrease.

Click [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16TyGwTtbLVDFDLlUv1YUMTKFxtANO6C-) to see the image of the buttons and progress bar that i created

Here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var form_count = 1;

    setProgressBar(form_count);

    function setProgressBar(curStep) {
      var i = 0;
      $.each($('input[type=submit]'), function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Revisit') {
          i++;
        }
      });
      var total = i * 4;
      var percent = total;
      percent = Math.floor(percent);
      if (percent > 100) {
        percent = 100;
      }
      $(".progress-bar")
        .css("width", percent + "%")
        .html(percent + "%");
    }
  });
```

This code work fine, but i need it dynamically.

Here is HTML code for all buttons i do same code

```
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="frmWrp">
        <form method="post" action="">
          <div class="heading">Quality Assurance</div>
          <div class="btn pull-right">
            <?php if ($feature_enable[0]['qa_mod'] == 1) { ?>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="user_configration1" value="<?php echo ($checkExist[0]['quality_assurance'] == 1) ? 'Revisit' : 'Visit'; ?>">
            <?php } else { ?>
            <button class="btn btn-default" disabled>Feature Not Enabled</button>
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

For example now i have 25 buttons and i do **var total = i * 4;** for getting **100%**, if buttons are less than i have to change 4 manually. but i need this dynamically.

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: Where is your decreased or increased?

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist i mean to say the buttons can be decrease in count or increase as well. According to count of buttons and check the status of button i want to create progress bar

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist see the updated post. now i share image as well of my buttons

Comment: Images are not very helpful. Can you share your HTML?

Comment: @Cat check html now

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general idea of how to use an eventListener to update the `width` property of a div's style attribute when a user clicks a "Submit" or "Revisit" button:

```js
// Identifies the progress bar
const progressBar = document.getElementsByClassName("progressBar")[0];

// Calls the `setProgressBar` function when the user clicks something
document.addEventListener("click", setProgressBar);

// Defines the `setProgressBar` function
function setProgressBar(event) {

  // Makes sure the click was on an `input` element with the `submit` type before proceeding
  if(
    event.target.tagName == "INPUT" &&
    event.target.getAttribute("type") == "submit"
  ){

    // Toggles the value of the clicked input element
    if(event.target.value == "Revisit"){ event.target.value = "Submit"; }
    else{ event.target.value = "Revisit"; }

    // Bascially the same as your original code -- updates the progressBar
    let i = 0;
    $.each($('input[type=submit]'), function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 'Revisit') { i++; }
    });
    const percent = Math.min(i * 25, 100);
    $(".progressBar").css("width", percent + "%").html(percent + "%");

  }
}
```

```css
#container{ width: 10ch; }
input[type=submit]{ margin-bottom: 0.2em; }
.progressBar{ height: 20px; background-color: yellow; width: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>

<div class = "progressBar"></div>
```